# Invisible enemy NPCs in SWTOR?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I recently started playing *Star Wars: The Old Republic Online*. Everything went fine on the starting planet, but once I hit my first off-world mission/flashpoint/what-have-you, I hit serious graphic trouble. Namely, I suddenly ran into enemy NPCs that I couldn't see. And I don't mean they were cloaked: I mean they were totally bodiless. If they had weapons I could see those, floating in the air and held by no one. Half the time I can't even target them, because I can't detect any bodies to target! AOE attacks will hurt them, and about half the time an AOE will cause me to target the NPCs once I've begun to hurt them, but most of the time unless they are accompanied by other, visible enemies that I can target first (which usually allows me to switch targets to the invisible ones using the keyboard controls), I just have to sit there and take damage until someone else kills these invisible jerks.

The problem seems to be linked to what *kind* of enemy it is, although I can't list all of the ones I've had trouble with, because they don't show up and neither do their names or identities. I can't even loot the corpses unless they're carrying a weapon; then I can click on the weapon and it will allow me to loot, but there's no body to click on even though the "loot indicator" lights up.

Some NPCs that are always invisible:

- Most of the droids on the Black Talon
- Vine Cats
- HK-droids
- Guild Lifter Droids
- Any "boss" droid (in those cases I can see forceshields etc, but not the bodies)

Additionally, some background elements do not render properly, but instead appear as round green cones. Mostly, numerous plants and some security chests.

I have updated all of my graphics, etc., and the computer I'm using is only a few weeks old anyway. It's an Inspiron 5748 with Windows 7, 64-bit, with i7 core. This happens on missions, in Heroic Areas, in Flashpoints, and just walking around the world at random. It affects both of my characters, a bounty hunter and a Jedi Sentinel, equally. They are currently level 12 and level 14, respectively, but have been having this problem since they were both level ten and left their starting worlds. My companions can target the invisible enemies, and so can any other players in the area. No one I've asked has experienced anything like this problem. I've tried playing the game in different graphics settings, but no matter how low or high I set my graphics, the exact same thing happens. This isn't just dangerous for my characters' health; it directly affects my ability to complete missions.

Any help, suggestions, or solutions would be great, thank you!

Comment: This sounds very much like a patching issue.  From the launcher, after signing in, can you do a Repair from the cog menu?

Comment: No, the Repair option is not engaged. I'm currently doing a total reinstall to see if that fixes it, but I'm not optimistic.

Comment: Not a fix but you can target enemies with tab. Hitting tab again will target the next one. Shift-tab will target the previous. You do not mention invisible allies or neutrals,  I think there is also an option to select those. Not sure what it is, but it should be in the key bindings

Comment: Thanks, but unless I've already managed to engage another enemy, the tab key doesn't register them either. So far, no allies have been invisible; just enemies, and the HK droids that some people have as companions.

Answer (score 1):

The reinstall appears to have worked, because I've played on both characters for a few hours now, and all of the NPCs are now visible and can be targeted.

Comment: I encountered this issue myself today, and a Repair fixed it.  I believe that the new BitRaider launcher was the cause for your problem -- it didn't finish patching properly, which is why you couldn't Repair, but it erroneously let you continue to play with certain assets missing.  I have the original launcher -- converting between the two is more than I can explain here, but is something you might want to look into.